# Where can we find in Oracle dictionary default attributes of index partition?

Tags: database, oracle

Let's assume i have some table with range partitions, range subpartitions and some local index corresponding with these subpartitions. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB 
(
  TAB_KEY1 NUMBER 
, TAB_KEY2 NUMBER 
, TAB_VAL NUMBER NOT NULL 
) 
TABLESPACE TBS_D_1 
PARTITION BY RANGE (TAB_KEY1) 
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (TAB_KEY2) 
(
  PARTITION PARTITION_1000 VALUES LESS THAN (1001) 
  (
    SUBPARTITION PARTITION_1000_1000 VALUES LESS THAN (1001)  
  )  
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TAB_I1 ON TAB (TAB_KEY1, TAB_KEY2) 
LOCAL 
TABLESPACE TBS_I_1;
```

When i set default tablespace for whole index:

```
ALTER INDEX TAB_I1 MODIFY DEFAULT ATTRIBUTES TABLESPACE TBS_I_2;
```

i am able to see this value in:

```
SELECT a.def_tablespace_name 
FROM all_part_indexes a 
WHERE a.index_name = 'TAB_I1';
```

But when i set default tablespace only for one partition:

```
ALTER INDEX TAB_I1 
MODIFY DEFAULT ATTRIBUTES FOR PARTITION partition_1000 TABLESPACE TBS_I_3;
```

i am not able to find this default tablespace anywhere in Oracle dictionary, but this value takes place in splitting of table subpartitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ALL_IND_PARTITIONS.TABLESPACE_NAME` instead of `ALL_PART_INDEXES.DEF_TABLESPACE_NAME`.